# How to access windows form controls from WPF control?

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to show a control in a form according to an event in a WPF control.

```
TheBoard theBoard = new TheBoard();
theBoard.keyboard.Visible = true;
```

even if I write:

```
theBoard.Close();
```

nothing will happen, if anybody can give me a solution please.

Comment: you should be way more specific. What are you trying to achiev, what is the expected behaviour, what happens instead, is TheBoard a winforms control????

Comment: TheBoard is a windows form, it has a control named keyboard, I want to make it visible. but I want that to be from a user defined (WPF) control. So I wonder why this is not working? thanks.

Comment: Inside a WPF app Windows Forms controls have to be hosted using `WindowsFormsHost`. Eg look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751761.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could raise an event from WPF control and subscribe that event in Windows form control. Here is a link which could give you the way to go.

http://www.a2zdotnet.com/View.aspx?Id=79#.T46J5bN-WUI